# using sed or awk to double quote comma separate and concatenate a list

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have the following list in a text file:

```
10.1.2.200
10.1.2.201
10.1.2.202
10.1.2.203
```

I want to encase in "double quotes", comma separate and join the values as one string.

Can this be done in sed or awk?

Expected output:

```
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203","10.1.2.204"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is something like this (in pseudo code):

1. Read a line;
2. Put the line in quotes;
3. Keep that quoted line in a stack or string;
4. At the end (or while constructing the string), join the lines together with a comma.

Depending on the language, that is fairly straightforward to do:

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{s=s ? s OFS "\"" $1 "\"" : "\"" $1 "\""} END{print s}' file
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```

Or, less 'wall of quotes' to define a quote character:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";q="\""}{s=s ? s OFS q$1q : q$1q} END{print s}' file
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.*)$/"\1"/' file | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g'
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```

(With Perl and Ruby, with a `join` function, it is easiest to push the elements onto a stack and then join that.)

Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'push @a, "\"$_\""; END{print join(",", @a)}' file
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```

Ruby:

```
$ ruby -ne 'BEGIN{@arr=[]}; @arr.push "\"#{$_.chomp}\""; END{puts @arr.join(",")}' file
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another alternative

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/' file | paste -sd,

"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS="\0" -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{NF--}$0=q$0q' file
```

should work for given example.

Tested with gawk:

```
kent$  cat f
10.1.2.200
10.1.2.201
10.1.2.202
10.1.2.203

kent$  awk -F'\n' -v RS="\0" -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{NF--}$0=q$0q' f
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$ awk '{o=o (NR>1?",":"") "\""$0"\""} END{print o}' file
"10.1.2.200","10.1.2.201","10.1.2.202","10.1.2.203"
```